# How to merge multiple linked list bundled together in a pointer to pointer into one?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

Here I'm experimenting with three linked list (list1, list2, list3), by putting them together in **lists. I'm trying to merge them but how do I even access/navigate through the values inside to start things off?

```
struct ListNode {
    int val;
    struct ListNode *next;
};

int main() {
    struct ListNode a; struct ListNode b; struct ListNode c;
    a.val = 1; b.val = 4; c.val = 5;
    a.next = &b; b.next = &c; c.next = NULL;
    struct ListNode* list1 = &a;

    struct ListNode d; struct ListNode e; struct ListNode f;
    d.val = 1; e.val = 3; f.val = 4;
    d.next = &e; e.next = &f; f.next = NULL;
    struct ListNode* list2 = &d;

    struct ListNode g; struct ListNode h;
    g.val = 2; h.val = 6;
    g.next = &h; h.next = NULL;
    struct ListNode* list3 = &g;

    list1->next = list2; list2->next = list3; list3->next = NULL;
    struct ListNode** lists = list1;
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do. Please elaborate. For example this record struct ListNode** lists = list1; does not make a sense.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to join the three lists serially, such that the last element of `list1` points to the first element of `list2` and so on?

You can simply do -

```
// c is the last element of list 1. list2 is already a pointer to a struct ListNode
c.next = list2 // this is exactly equivalent to c.next = &d


// similarly, f is the last element of list 2. list3 is already a pointer to a struct ListNode
f.next = list3 // this is exactly equivalent to f.next = &g
```

The original lists were

`a -> b -> c ->`

`d -> e -> f ->`

`g -> h ->`

After the above steps, you will have -

`a -> b -> c -> d -> e -> f -> g -> h`

You're mistake was that you were assuming that `list`, `list2`, and `list3` refer to the lists as a whole. They are simple pointers to the first elements of each list so -

`list1->next = list2`

set the `next` value of the **node pointed to by `list1` (`a`)** to the address of the first node of `list2`

You have to find the **last** element of a list and assign it to the first element of the list you want to merge.

---

Unless, this is a one-off thing, I would recommend you define a subroutine that takes a pointers to two lists and joins them serially. Something like this -

```
void joinNodes(ListNode* first, ListNode* second) {
    // loop through first until the last element (say, x) is found
    // set next of x to second
    // end
}
```

The implementation is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I see what my problem here is and thanks for pointing it out. However, I do not understand how.....let's say an array of 20 linked list is store in ListNode** lists.....how do I access the first and last node of all 20 linked list stored in lists.....so that I can make a function and combine them into one linked list

Comment: A `ListNode**` stores a pointer to a pointer to a `ListNode`, **not** a `ListNode` itself; Additionally, you have just a linked list, **not** an array of linked lists. To get the the first and last nodes of a list you just have to step one-by-one through each element of the list.

If I had to guess, I think you are misunderstanding what a pointer or a pointer-to-a-pointer is. I would recommend that you refresh your understanding of pointers and dereferencing and try to figure out if a `ListNode**` (a pointer-to-a-pointer) is really needed in your case.

Comment: struct LinkList {
    struct ListNode *head;
    struct ListNode *tail;
};
To add a node to the head of a link list you would do something like this : 
newnode->next = linklist->head;
linklist->head = newnode;
To add a node to the end of a link list you would do something like this :
linklist->tail->next = newnode;
linklist->tail = newnode;

Answer (score 0):

FYI : Sometimes a link list class is a different thing than a node on that linked list. Sometimes they are identical classes. In your case you are using a ListNode as both the linklist and the nodes on the linked list.

If you want to append the lists such that you get
1->4->5->1->3->4->2->6->
you would want to implement a helper function that would iterate to the END of the link list and return the last element. It's been a while since I coded any C so expect syntax errors, but something like :

```
ListNode* getLastNodeFromLinkList(ListNode* n){
    if(n == NULL) return NULL;
    while(n->next != NULL){
        n = n->next;
    }
    return n;
}
```

Then you can do something like :

```
struct ListNode* x;
x = getLastNodeFromLinkList(list1);
x->next = list2;
x = getLastNodeFromLinkList(list2);
x->next = list3;
```